# Override environment variable created locally in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables

I have 2 properties files that I wish send their content via mail. What I do is so:

1. Read those files with [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)

[image]

2. Use those varibles as so to send the via mail:
   [image]

Those config files are containing different link and date I see in email the same output:

```
Android Mobile Client Release Notes CH

Link: ftp://testlink_CH
Date: 28/06/2016

Android Mobile Client Release Notes PL

Link: ftp://testlink_CH
Date: 28/06/2016
```

Whitch meanns when ${Link} is set its not oveeriden even if I try "unset" command.

```
[EnvInject] - Injecting environment variables from a build step.
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties file path 'AndroidDev/CH/config.properties'
[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties content 
LINK_CH=${Link}
DATE_CH=${Date}

[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
[mvandroid] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson108948632979693109.sh
+ unset Link
+ unset Date
[EnvInject] - Injecting environment variables from a build step.
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties file path 'AndroidDev/PL/config.properties'
[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties content 
LINK_PL=ftp://testlink_CH
DATE_PL=28/06/2016
```

Can you please help me with this or give me you incite on this?

Comment: You cannot unset system environment variables. You can only remove inherited environment variables.

Comment: Can you elaborate please? I am relatively new to this... I am setting system environment variables? And what is  inherited environment variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this is happening lies in the way the env-inject plugin works.  If you use both **"Properties File Path"** and **"Properties Content"** fields in one invocation, they are not processed sequentially but are instead handled in parallel.  Therefore, when you are setting `$LinkPL`, the value of `$Link` is still old.  The solution is to **make two env-inject steps**, one to inject the props file and the next to make use of the results.

Example:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Additionally, you **cannot unset** a value of a variable in a shell step the way you are attempting to do it.  Unsetting it will only affect that shell step.