# Jenkins run a failing test n times

Tags: bash, jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying rerun a test n times on failure in Jenkins. I've seen Naginator, but my team would prefer not to add additional plugins.
(Note: we use EnvInject to inject environmental variables into the build process)

The next idea was to keep a variable with the number of times to retry, and decrement it on each new build. There was a stack overflow link (that I'm struggling to find at the moment) suggesting a groovy script that looks like this

```
def map = [:]
Int newRetries = RETRIES.toInteger() - 1
map.put(“RETRIES”, newRetries)
return map
```

However, groovy scripts in the "prepare an environment to run" section need admin privilages (which again my team would prefer to avoid).

The next idea was to use a property file and just do something along the lines of `echo "RETRIES=$((RETRIES-1))" > env.properties` and add an Inject Environmental variable step that reads in env.properties.

The problem is that within our Jenkins bash script `echo "RETRIES=$((RETRIES-1))"` prints "RETRIES=$((RETRIES-1))"

In a local terminal I can run

```
RETRIES=5
echo "RETRIES=$((RETRIES-1))"

> RETRIES=4
```

, but in Jenkins, RETRIES-1 doesn't get evaluated. Do any of you have an idea of why?

Comment: In the bash script you have RETREIS and then RETRIES??

Comment: @RamanSailopal Sorry about that, that was a typo copying text over. I figured out what was happening and am posting a solution now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found 3 mistakes that I was making.

1. Jenkins pipelines execute a single step in parallel. This means you can't write to and read from a file in different portions of the same step without reading from the unupdated file (in practice) (From this stackoverflow [Override environment variable created locally in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077165/override-environment-variable-created-locally-in-jenkins))
2. The default shell on Jenkins is /usr/bin/sh which isn't necessarily bash. I explicitly ran my script with `bash -c "echo $Var"` (the real issue here was that the remote machines were windows, oops)
3. My pipeline was failing before reading in the updated variable value from the file. I've moved the reading step earlier in the pipeline.